# How to compare the content of multiple txt file in bash shell and delete the one (file) which is duplicate

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I am trying to achieve this is Mac OS, tried to achieve similar by using fdupes but didn't work. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- There are 100 files in directory 'alpha'
- Pick one file A and compare it with each remaining file in the directory 'alpha'
- If content of file A matches any file (duplicate), delete the duplicate file
- Move to file B, and compare with the remaining file, and do the same (check for duplicate)
- Repeat the same until all files are checked for duplicates. Remaining files should be unique

#### Update

I modified a bit something similar I found here, but I have to run it multiple times to take out the duplicates. It is not detecting duplicates in a single run (have to run it multiple times to detect duplicate). Not sure if it is working correctly

```
use Digest::MD5;
%check = ();
while (<*>) {
    -d and next;
    $fname = "$_";
    print "checking .. $fname\n";
    $md5 = getmd5($fname) . "\n";
    if ( !defined( $check{$md5} ) ) {
        $check{$md5} = "$fname";
    }
    else {
        print "Found duplicate files: $fname and $check{$md5}\n";
        print "Deleting duplicate $check{$md5}\n";
        unlink $check{$md5};
    }
}

sub getmd5 {
    my $file = "$_";
    open( FH, "<", $file ) or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
    binmode(FH);
    my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
    $md5->addfile(FH);
    close(FH);
    return $md5->hexdigest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should limit the number of times that you have to read each file's contents:

1. Inventory the files using [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) or some similar method.

   a. Build a hash relating file sizes and [`MD5::Digest`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5)  to a list of file names.
2. Compare likely duplicates only.  Matching file size and digest.

The following is untested:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;
use Digest::MD5;

my $dir = dir('.');

my %files_per_digest;

# Inventory Directory
while ( my $file = $dir->next ) {
    my $size   = $file->stat->size;
    my $digest = do {
        my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
        $md5->addfile( $file->openr );
        $md5->hexdigest;
    };
    push @{ $files_per_digest{"$size - $digest"} }, $file;
}

# Compare likely duplicates only
for my $files ( grep { @$_ > 1 } values %files_per_digest ) {
    # Sort by alpha
    @$files = sort @$files;
    print "Comparing: @files\n";

    for my $i ( reverse 0 .. $#files ) {
        for my $j ( 0 .. $i - 1 ) {
            my $fh1 = $files->[$i]->openr;
            my $fh2 = $files->[$j]->openr;

            my $diff = 0;
            while ( !eof($fh1) && !eof($fh2) ) {
                $diff = 1, last if scalar(<$fh1>) ne scalar(<$fh2>);
            }

            if ( $diff or !eof($fh1) or !eof($fh2) ) {
                print "   $files->[$i] ($i) is duplicate of $files->[$j] ($j)\n";
                $files->[$i]->remove();
                splice @$files, $i, 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying following (modified a script from another user). It detects some duplicates, but when I run the script it again detects some duplicates.. and so on until no more duplicates are seen. Just modified my original post to reflect the cod.

Answer (score 0):

I've used rdfind in the past with very good success. It's very accurate, fast, and seems to run leaner than fdupes. According to [RDFind's web site](http://rdfind.pauldreik.se/) (http://rdfind.pauldreik.se/), it can be installed using MacPorts.